# Class members that are optionally static depending on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Imagine two classes, `StaticFoo` and `NonStaticFoo`, that are **identical** except that the class members are static in `StaticFoo`, but not in `NonStaticFoo`.
Simple example:

```
class StaticFoo {
  static void bar();
  static int v;
};

class NonStaticFoo {
  void bar();
  int v;
};
```

Is it possible to factor out a template class `Foo` to avoid code duplication?
So that then one could just use something like

```
using StaticFoo = Foo<true>;
using NonStaticFoo = Foo<false>;
```

Comment: "Static classes" are not very good practice in C++. Use namespaces.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and reflect on how your question fits it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can think of it as a `template<typename T>` Registrator class for given types that is currently used statically everywhere in my code base, but that I would slowly like to convert to a non-static class.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense, static and non-static things are fundamentally different, its not an incremental difference

Comment: @PasserBy It's incremental in the sense that I would change the `Registrator<Foo>` one after each other for the different `Foo`s.

Comment: Huh? I mean, why would static stuff work when a non-static one will and vice versa? Actually, just give a simple use case example

Comment: @PasserBy I don't understand your question. If it helps, imagine, for the example above, that `void bar() { ++v; }`. This is like a global counter if the class is static, but you can also use it as a local counter if you instantiate it in a non-static fashion. The class does the same things in both cases.

Comment: Scratch what I said, provide a sample use case. The global counter and local counter example for instance, has a pretty huge difference in semantics and you would need to rewrite quite some stuff.

Comment: I can't see how to do this with a template (and avoiding code duplication), but you could use a macro (I know its bad). Let me know you need any assistance with that.

Comment: @oLen: Unfortunately `static` is not an expression like `noexcept`. So you can specialize a template based on some condition, but without a macro you cannot avoid code duplication. I refrain from posting as an answer because I feel like it would boil down to saying "no"

Comment: @AndyG thanks! Apparently the answer is indeed just "no". If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to factor out a template class Foo to avoid code duplication?

"no"

Unfortunately `static` is not parameterized by an expression like `noexcept` is, so you can't say something like `static(false)`.

Without using a macro, you're forced to specialize a template such that you can have `static` members in the specialization:

```
template<bool = false>
class Foo{
   void bar();
   int v;
};
template<>
class Foo<true>{
   static void bar();
   static int v;
};
```